# There is a problem with the request entity - You are not allowed to create 'iOS' profile with App ID 'XXXX'

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I am tryin to upload a new app to the App Store. It was built with expo and I am now tryin to build it using EAS.

I've uploaded my first and only app a few months ago.

From the root of my project I run:

`eas build --platform ios`

- Do you want to log in to your Apple account - I choose yes
- Apple ID (presented and correct) - I click yes

Then the following

Restoring session C:\Users\Yanay.app-store\auth\yanaycodes@gmail.com\cookie
Team My Name (My ID)

Provider My Name (Some Numbers maybe another ID)

√ Logged in Local session

✔ Bundle identifier registered MY.ACTUAL.BUNDLE.IDENTIFIER

✔ Synced capabilities: Enabled: Push Notifications | Disabled: Sign In with Apple

✔ Synced capability identifiers: No updates

✔ Fetched Apple distribution certificates

- Reuse this distribution certificate?
  Cert ID: SOME ID, Serial number: SOME SERIAL NUMBER, Team ID: MY TEAM ID, Team name: MY NAME (Individual) - I choose yes
- Generate a new Apple Provisioning Profile? - I choose yes

And then I get
✖ Failed to create Apple provisioning profile
Failed to set up credentials.
There is a problem with the request entity - You are not allowed to create 'iOS' profile with App ID 'APP ID'.
Error: build command failed.

What is happening?

I went to my developer account and I can even find that APP ID it shows me (last error log) in any of the apps (there like two there, one was just created to support apple log in).

How can I fix this?

This is my app.json if that helps

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My Apps Name",
    "slug": "MyAppsName",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#202022"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "my.package.url",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "This app uses the microphone to allow you to capture audio as a note.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "This app needs access to the photo library to allow you to upload photos as notes.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to allow you to capture photos as notes.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "This app needs access to your location to allow you to capture your location as a note."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "my.package.url",
      "versionCode": 5,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#202022"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS",
        "android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE",

        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "my-project-id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```